# Set date and time in stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, date, time

I am currently having a problem printing the output using C# asp.net. I've built a stored procedure containing a query that will select the username if the login date and time that the user is trying to login on the website is in between a specific start and end time. So here is my code using sql server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[access]
    (@DateNow as varchar(50),  
     @studentnum as varchar(50)
    )
AS
IF EXISTS(SELECT StudentNum 
          FROM users, enlistment 
          WHERE StudentNum LIKE '13%' 
          AND @DateNow BETWEEN '2016-09-28 00:00:00.000' AND endtime)
    SELECT username FROM users, enlistment 
    WHERE StudentNum LIKE '13' + @studentnum 
    AND @DateNow BETWEEN starttime AND endtime
```

Here is my code in c#

```
SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("access", connection); 
SqlParameter useraccess = new SqlParameter("studentnum", fourNum);
string datenow = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd yyyy hh:mm");
SqlParameter date = new SqlParameter("DateNow", datenow);

cmd3.Parameters.Add(useraccess);
cmd3.Parameters.Add(date);
cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
lblStatus.Text = Convert.ToString(cmd3.ExecuteScalar());
```

After executing, `lblStatus.Text` should display the username of the person trying to login. unfortunately, the website is not showing it. Is there a problem in my code?

Comment: "set nocount on" should be the first command in your stored proc

Comment: Use the **most appropriate** datatypes - always! Don't use  `varchar(50)` for a parameter `@DateNow` that is **clearly** a date (or date&time) - use `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` instead!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Also the procedure returns nothing when the if exists() returns false

Comment: Why are you executing the command again when you are using it to fill a `DataTable`?  Either just pull the result from the `DataTable` or don't fill the `DataTable` at all if you don't need it.

Comment: oh, i needed the data table for the following line of codes @DStanley

Comment: So why not just use `dt.Rows[0][0]` instead of `ExecuteScalar`?  There should not be a need to go to the database again.

Comment: @GuidoG hello! what's 'set nocount on' for?

Comment: oh! okay noted! @DStanley

Comment: @DStanley it still doesn't show the output :(

Comment: about "set nocount on" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx

Comment: @DStanley it says that it is empty, but when I try executing it through sql-server it shows the username of the person

Comment: If you debug it does it return the right value?  If so then the problem is somewhere else - are you perhaps overwriting `lblStatus.Text` somewhere else?  Is this happening on page load or some other event handler?

Comment: @GuidoG i just tried adding set nocount on but still no success :(

Comment: @Briana I did not say it was the solution to your problem but without this the procedure would never be able to do what you want so you have to do it anyway

Comment: yep, it is returning the right value. and I'm not overwriting lblStatus.Text somewhere else. :( I think there's a problem storing the date and time? I tried removing the scalar value 'DateNow' and it works with having the studentnum only. that's why I tried using varchar as my datatype for my 'DateNow'

Comment: @GuidoG noted! thanks for that :)

Comment: What is the point of the IF statement? It is the same rows as the query. Just run the query once. As it is posted you have to run the query once to see if it will return any rows and if it does you go back to the table to get the same row again.

Comment: why pass the date as a varchar in stead of DateTime ? Depending on your sql server settings this could be wrongly converted back to date. Use DateTime or Date as datatype

Comment: what happens if you run the query direct in sql server managment studio ? do you get the result you expect ?

Comment: @GuidoG actually it was in datetime format, I just tried using varchar hoping that it would solve the problem. Unfortunately, it did not. When I tried running it in sql server, I got the result I expected. But when I try running the website, lblStatus.Text doesn't display the output I am expecting. :(

Comment: @SeanLange oh because I have an else if after that which is also similar with the query above but with different start and endtime and different studnumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a fix on your use of Date, not an answer as to why you are not getting the expected result.**

Always use the native data types in .net and sql server, never a string representation of the type!

Changed sp signature

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[access]
    (@DateNow as Date,  -- change this to Date or DateTime or DateTime2 accordingly
     @studentnum as varchar(50)
    )
-- rest of stored proc does not have to change
```

Changed c# code

```
SqlParameter date = new SqlParameter("@DateNow", SqlDbType.Date) {Value = System.DateTime.Now.Date};
// or with time
// SqlParameter date = new SqlParameter("@DateNow", SqlDbType.DateTime) {Value = System.DateTime.Now};
```

Comment: hello! is this in the format "September 29, 2016 11:31pm" ?

Comment: @Briana - DateTime types do not have a `format`. They are structures. Formats should only be applicable to the presentation layer (at the point your user wants to visually "see" the date/time). In your database `starttime` and `endtime` should also be of type `Date`, `DateTime` or `DateTime2` (not varchar).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Briana - If this does fix your issue please consider accepting an answer (see [How to accept SO answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)).